# Flutter streambuilder not updating its sub child widget

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-streambuilder

Im trying to create authentication for my flutter app, for now I have two pages, loginpage and homepage. When the user has logged in, the application must automatically display the homepage. If not logged in, then they must go to the login page.

The application runs perfectly but when I want to change it, when the user has not logged in it will go to the landing page and there is a login page and register page in it, the problem is now the application does not immediately change its appearance, but the application must be restarted first.

```
// this is works
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) return HomePage();
      return LoginPage();
    },
  ),
 
// this doesn't work
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) return HomePage();
      return LandingPage(); // landingpage has 2 button to go to register and loginpage
    },
  ),
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbcH0.png)

Comment: It's very likely your authstate *isn't* changing between your register and login pages.  You'll need some controller at the next layer down to sequence you to the proper subwidget.

Comment: i ithink it changing, because when i rrestart the app the changes appear so we can say that the auth is changing but the ui isn't